# ASPNETCORE variables for testing in iOs app settings development not found

Tags: ios, asp.net-core, testing, environment-variables

I'm using Rider in iOs and when I'm throwing the test the .Net application is trying to take the `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT` from the System variable and obviously it doesn't find it.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException The configuration file 'appsettings..json' was not found and is not optional.
```

Is there a way to set the variable in the iOS system and not have to rename the file to appsettings..json by deleting Development?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in Runtime Config the environment variable works!

[image]